# How to Construct a Database to be Used on iOS and on the Web

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, xml, core-data

I am making an iPhone application and Website simultaneously and I want a shared database between the two.  I know about some of the options although none of them seem to work perfectly.  Like Core Data which will be very nice on the iPhone side, although I havent found a way to access the same information in something other than Obj-c.  SQLite is another option, I might not be right, but it supposedly does not work well for servers and being accessed simultaneously from different places.  Or I could do XML which seems easy on both sides but it seems like thats the slowest option and will have a huge drag on performance if im going to be reading it from a server all the time.

Any help would be appreciated, and if you know of any other solutions I will be glad to give them a try.
Thanks in advance,
Jordan

Comment: Is there a real need to have two databases?  For example are you trying to support users who need data offline?  Having two databases starts to cause problems along the lines of "Who has the definitive data?"  Or to put it another way "A man with one watch always knows what time it, a man with two watches never knows".

Comment: No the database is going to be entirely online I just need to access it on the iOS device and the Website and maybe I'll keep a cache on the iOS device but it will only be in one place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought of using a MySQL backend on your server, and then providing your mobile application with an API?

This takes the hassle out of data synchronisation and also provides you with a good level of sustainability and scalability.

I hope this helps.

Josh.

Comment: I meant create your own... Just write some basic code in PHP that you can request data from :)

Comment: How would I do that with PHP? sorry im asking so many questions I just am not sure how you would interact Objective-c with MySQL using PHP? Is there a tutorial you could point me to? Or should I just know this? lol :-)

Comment: PHP isn't MySQL... PHP is a language with some useful, easy to use built-in functions allowing access to a MySQL database...

Comment: Yeah I meant that I just have a hard time with words lol I'm working on it now thank you very much for your help, php is perfect for the job